# Have issues getting data to display on my web application

Tags: django, database, django-models

I am trying to get the "About us" information from my database to my web application but its not displaying, what could be wrong...

here is the code from the database

```
class About(models.Model):
    about_us = models.TextField()
    achieve = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image_abt = models.ImageField(upload_to="admin_pics", null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "About Us"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.about_us
```

and here is the Html code `

```
{% extends 'jtalks/base.html' %}
{% load static %}


{%block content%}
<section id="about-home">
    <h2>About Us</h2>
</section>

<section id="about-container">
    {% for about in abouts %}
    <div class="about-img">
        <img src="{{ about.image_abt.url }}" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="about-text">
        <h2>Welcome to TechEduca, Enhance your skills with best Online Courses</h2>
        <p>{ about.about_us}</p>

        <div class="about-fe">
            <img src="images/fe1.png" alt="">
            <div class="fe-text">
                <h5>400+ Courses</h5>
                <p>You can start and finish one of these popular courses in under our site</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="about-fe">
            <img src="images/fe2.png" alt="">
            <div class="fe-text">
                <h5>Lifetime Access</h5>
                <p>You can start and finish one of these popular courses in under our site</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Nothing is displaying in the frontend of the website.

Comment: Can you show the view that renders the template ?

Comment: def about(request):
    return render(request, 'jtalks/about.html')

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing the view. You forgot to pass data to your template. To do that you have to create the queryset and pass that into a dictionary like below. Add the context variable to your render method so you can access the data in the template.

```
def about(request):
    about = About.objects.all()
    context = {
    'abouts': about,    
    }
    return render(request, 'jtalks/about.html', context)
```

also, in your html code i see `{ about.about_us}`, but you have to use double curly brackets: `{{ about.about_us }}`